# webRTC How to set video width height in iPhone safari browser

Tags: safari, webrtc

if i write like this , video does not show out anymore

```
navigator.getMedia({
  video: {
    width:300,
    height:300,
    facingMode: "environment"
  }, 
  audio: false 
},
```

The video below will appear, but the size is wrong

```
navigator.getMedia({
  video: {
    facingMode: "environment"
  }, 
  audio: false 
},
```

if i set width and height to square shape in html video tag , and add a border to it ,The camera still according to their own ratio , The sides of the square will be left blank .

image link :
http://m.qpic.cn/psb?/714818507/CGRo3c1MM8BIp1iMvuMp2JxDwz2H0YNzUnWdB26vYvc!/b/dGgBAAAAAAAA&bo=vAKAAgAAAAARFxw!&rf=viewer_4

```
<video id="video" width="300px" height="300px" autoPlay playsInline></video>
```

By the way , in iPhone safari browser, Written by react.js .Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong :

```
<video id="video" width="300px" height="300px" autoPlay playsInline></video>
```

Square is not standard but you can make it.

Let's try with  :

```
<video id="video" width="300" height="300" autoPlay playsInline></video>
```

Look video player as normal html element nothing special. Just setup css to fit.

You can use px intro style arg :

```
style="width:300px;height:300px;border:solid red 1px;"
```

Also i suggest 480 width and 320 height.

Comment: Hi, I upload a image about my problem, I need to achieve it like scan QR code feature,  so square needed and camera have to fill the entire square . And I tryed width="300" height="300" but not solved.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a `getUserMedia()` video feed from camera of an arbitrary aspect ratio. The picture you are going to get will generally be 4:3 or 16:9. It's your job to place it correctly with HTML and CSS. In your given case, this means zooming in the image and cutting off its top and bottom so you'll only be showing the central square area.

**Edit:** There you go, nice and square (using a fix from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30700144/responsive-object-fit-cover-fix-on-chrome#30887877)): https://jsfiddle.net/mp244ptf/8/

Comment: Sorry , how can i add css to the image ?  Like i give width and height to <video> tag , it's no effect on the camera picture

Comment: video: {
    width:300,
    height:300,
  }, After I set the width and height and open in chrome by my loptop, the camera picture can fill the box , but in my iphone safari it doesnt work

Comment: navigator.getMedia({
  video: {
    width:300,
    height:300,
  },  After I set the width and height and open in chrome by my loptop, the camera picture can fill the box , but in my iphone safari video doesnt show out and no matter how small size I changed ,video doesnt show out

Comment: Added a link to a fiddle to show you how to achieve this.