# Google chrome won't resize video banner

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

So I'm trying to make this website with a video for the banner, now it works perfectly in Firefox (my primary browser) but whenever I run it in chrome the video doesn't resize and covers the navigation menu. I haven't yet tried this in edge so I can't say yet how it works there but I need it to work in Firefox and Chrome mainly.

I'm using an unedited .mp4 video in a code block like so

```
    <header class="main-header">
    <video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
        <source src="images/hotel.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    </header>
```

And the css,

```
#myVideo {
position: relative;
bottom: 100;
  object-fit: cover;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
```

}

I can add the entire code block from the home-page is that helps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Responsive object-fit: cover fix on Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30700144/responsive-object-fit-cover-fix-on-chrome)

Comment: I tried having one and two copies of 'object-fit: cover' but it didn't change anything and if I don't have it it won't stretch the full width of the page